# Gulp 4 bower install doesn't trigger finished

Tags: bower, gulp-4

I'm using gulp 4. When trying to install bower dependencies using gulp, the bower task never finishes. Both the example below actually install dependencies.

### Example 1

```
var run = require('gulp-run');
gulp.task('bower', function(done) {
  run('./node_modules/.bin/bower install', {cwd: './temp'}).exec(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;

    done();
  });
});
```

This never finishes. It just hangs.

### Example 2

```
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return bower({cwd: './temp'});
});
```

This one throws `The following tasks did not complete: bower. Did you forget to signal async completion?` after it completes. But since it throws, I can't continue my `gulp.series`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using the regular 'bower' package, rather than 'gulp-bower'.  There's a programmatic API for bower that can be used with native promises in order to work with Gulp 4.

For example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    bower = require('bower');

gulp.task('bower:install', function() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        bower.commands.install(undefined, undefined, {
            cwd: './temp'
        }).on('end', resolve);
    });
});
```

You'll notice that I'm using ES6 arrow syntax for the anonymous function. You can use ES6 for gulp as long as your gulpfile is named 'gulpfile.babel.js' and you have 'babel-core' installed alongside gulp (local install is fine).